# Sending signal from parent to child process after parent waits in C program

Tags: c, signals, signal-processing, child-process

I am attempting to send SIGUSR1 to my child process, child_b, after my parent process waits. However, my handler for sigusr1 is not executing and printing my message "pong quitting" at the end of the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>


int fd[2][2];

void sig_handler(int signum) {
    if (signum == SIGUSR1) {
        printf("pong quitting\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void f1() {
    int x = 0;
    close(fd[0][0]);
    close(fd[1][1]);
    while (x <= 100) {
        printf("ping: %d\n", x);
        x++;
        if (write(fd[0][1], &x, sizeof(int)) < 0) {
            printf("Error writing f1\n");
        }
        if (read(fd[1][0], &x, sizeof(int)) < 0) {
            printf("Error reading f1\n");
        }
    }
    close(fd[0][1]);
    close(fd[1][0]);

} 

void f2() {
    int x = 0;
    close(fd[0][1]);
    close(fd[1][0]);
    while (x <= 100) {
        if (read(fd[0][0], &x, sizeof(int)) < 0) {
            printf("Error reading f2\n");
        }
        if (x <= 100)
            printf("pong: %d\n", x);
        x++;
        if (write(fd[1][1], &x, sizeof(int)) < 0) {
            printf("Error writing f2\n");
        }
    }
    close(fd[0][0]);
    close(fd[1][1]);
}

int main(void) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (pipe(fd[i]) < 0) {
            printf("Error opening pipe.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    pid_t child_a = fork();

    if (child_a < 0) {
        printf("Error forking child_a.\n");
        return 2;
    }

    if (child_a == 0) {
        f1();
    } else {
        pid_t child_b = fork();

        if (child_b < 0) {
            printf("Error forking child_b.\n");
            return 3;
        }

        if (child_b == 0) {
            signal(SIGUSR1, sig_handler);
            f2();
        }

        else {
            waitpid(child_a, NULL, 0);
            waitpid(child_b, NULL, 0);
            kill(child_b, SIGUSR1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried sleeping both the parent and child, as well as rearranging the order of wait and kill; however, I can not get the signal handler to execute. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're not sending the signal until after both children have exited. How do you expect the child to process the signal?

Comment: Obligatory aside: `printf` is not an *async-signal-safe* function, as outlined in [`man 7 signal-safety`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).

Comment: @Oka Neither is `exit()`

Comment: Did you really intend to read  the same variable from the pipe that you're using to control the number of iterations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Killing after `wait` is just fundamentally wrong: the program is dead and gone, you'd either be getting `ESCHR` or `kill` an innocent unrelated process.

If you move the `wait` before `kill`, then the problems become `child_b` finishing two quickly (try running it under `strace -f` and see `child_b` is already a zombie by the time the `kill` runs). Adding some `sleep(a_lot);` or `pause();` at the end of `child_b` would help there.

```
    if (child_b == 0) {
        signal(SIGUSR1, sig_handler);
        f2();
        pause(); //+
    }

    else {
        waitpid(child_a, NULL, 0);
        kill(child_b, SIGUSR1); //^
        waitpid(child_b, NULL, 0); //v
    }
```

For added async-signal safety, you could also change the handler to be async-signal-safe:

```
void sig_handler(int signum) {
    char m[]="pong quitting\n";
    write(1,m,sizeof(m)-1);
    _exit(1);
}
```